# Checking if pandas row value is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I loaded an excel file, let's call it test.xlsx into a data frame. I'm iterating over the rows of the dataframe and loading them into class objects. The problem is, some of the rows are blank, and if that is the case then I would like to fill in my own value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'test.xlsx')
for row in df.rows:
            id = row['Id']
            name = row['Name']
            number = row['Number']
```

The column that I'm specifically concerned with is number. Some rows have a value, while others don't. What is a simple conditional I can use that doesn't take up too many lines. e.g.:

```
## (within the for loop)
if row['Number'] == NaN:
    number = **MY CHOICE OF NUMBER**
else:
    number = row['Number']
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
df['Number'] = df['Number'].fillna(your_default_value)
```